# Calculation in the phasor domain

Tags: phasor

I have to calculate \$|I_L|\$ in this circuit (which is in the phasor domain and at sinusoidal regime).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fja5wD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The given data is: \$I_g=2 mA\$,\$X_L=10\Omega\$ (in rms).

I did it this way: \$|I_L|=|I_g| |\frac{R}{R+X_L}|=1 mA\$, but the result gives \$\sqrt 2 mA\$. Why is that?

EDIT:

Actually I wasn't doing it with phasor method.

Here is the phasor diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1EUNj.png)</sup>

So \$|I_L|=\sqrt{I_g^2-I_R^2}\$, but what's \$I_R\$?

Comment: Ig = 2mA is given. Also you haven't attempted the problem using phasors.

Comment: @Chu: I edited the question. Why didn't I do it with phasors?

Comment: Show your phasor diagram.

Comment: @Chu I edited the question. Check it out,please.

Comment: I calculated the voltage \$V\$ across \$R\$ and \$L\$. It is \$V=\frac{10 j10}{10+j10}=...=\frac{10}{\sqrt{2}}\$. So \$I_R=\frac{V}{I_R}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$ and \$|I_L|=\sqrt{I_g^2-I_R^2}=...=\sqrt{\frac{7}{2}}\$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: The angle for I_L should be -90 deg (I lags V for an inductor). I_L is of length V/XL = V/10; I_R is of length V/R = V/10, and the resultant current phasor is of length 2mA (and starts at the origin, not at the tip of the I_R phasor). You can now complete the problem.

Comment: You're right with the angles, but \$I_R=\frac{V}{10}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$. Anyway, if I calc it with the current divider I get \$I_R=\sqrt{2}\$. So what's wrong?

Comment: Excuse-me. My mistake in doing calculations. It's all fine now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phasors are expressed analytically as complex numbers, therefore in the phasor domain the usual current divider formula is:

\$
I_L = I_g \dfrac{R}{R+jX_L}
\$

Hence, using the modulus operator on both members and using its properties you get:

\$
\left|I_L\right| = \left|I_g \dfrac{R}{R+jX_L}\right| = 
\left|I_g\right| \dfrac{\left|R\right|}{\left|R+jX_L\right|} =
\left|I_g\right| \dfrac{\left|R\right|}{\sqrt{R^2+X_L^2}}=
2 \, mA \dfrac{10}{\sqrt{10^2+10^2}}= 2 \, mA \dfrac 1 {\sqrt 2} = \sqrt 2 \, mA
\$

Comment: As the question uses 'phasor' I would guess that a solution using complex notation is not what the teacher was looking for.

Comment: @Lorenzo Donati Thank you! Couldn't it be solved with phasor diagrams too?

Comment: @sleax, yes of course. Hint: take the voltage across R and L as the reference phasor and draw the current phasors for R and L relative to the voltage phasor.

Comment: @Chu Well, at least in my experience, if the teacher asked for a *phasor **diagram*** you would be right. But, at least in Italy, when asking to use *phasors* the teacher might mean what here is also known as the *phasor(ial) method*, i.e. using the complex representation of sinusoidal quantities. So the interpretation of the request may depend on the OP's "locale".

Comment: @LorenzoDonati I'm from Italy, as you. I think the problem meant what you said,but it's interesting to see it both ways.

Comment: Well, it says 'phasor domain' and not 'complex domain'. I give similar exercises to my students because using phasors gives much more insight into problems than mechanistic complex number manipulation.

Comment: Italy 2-1 Wales!

Comment: @Chu I agree with you on the usefulness of phasor diagrams, but bear in mind that here in Italy when you say "complex domain" it could be interpreted as the same as "s-domain", i.e. L-transform method. Sadly terminology is not that uniform across countries (and across authors as well!).

Comment: @Chu I guess that was a soccer-related joke ;-) I'm not a big fan of that sport ... surprisingly, for an Italian :-P :-D